# Java Regex to list

Tags: java, regex

```
String myString = "({Abc} + {CdE}/{XYZ})";
```

How do I extract values in {x} and store everything to an ArrayList?

```
list[0] = "Abc";
list[1] = "cDe";
list[2] = "XYZ";
```

Thanks!

Comment: How should the list look for your particular example?

Comment: Also, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) class.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{(.+?)\\}").matcher(myString);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find())
{
    list.add(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martijn, but some of cases it match it with a brackets but not just a pure string.

Comment: Are you sure you tried the edited code (33 minutes old)?